# Magento 2 System Configuration Custom setting for Module Failed

Tags: magento-2.1

Got problem here, I'm adding a store configuration and got this error

```
 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento3\app\code\Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Iterator.php on line 59
```

here is the system.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>  
        <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd"> 
    <system>
        <tab id="news" translate="label" sortOrder="1">
            <label>News</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="news" translate="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" 
showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Latest News</label>
            <tab>news</tab>
            <resource>News_LatestNews::system_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" 
showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Settings</label>
                <field id="enable_in_frontend" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" 
showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable in frontend</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="head_title" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="2" 
showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Head title</label>
                    <comment>Fill head title of news list page at here</comment>
                    <validate>required-entry</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="lastest_news_block_position" translate="label" type="select" 
sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Lastest news block position</label>
                    <source_model>News\LatestNews\Model\System\Config\LastestNews\Position</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
```

this is my acl.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>  
           <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
<acl>
    <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                    <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                        <resource id="News_LatestNews::system_config" title="Simple News Section" />
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

I'm new in magento so I really need a help thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems like you miss to end **< config />** in **system.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>  
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd"> 
        <system>
            <tab id="news" translate="label" sortOrder="1">
                <label>News</label>
            </tab>
            <section id="news" translate="label" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Latest News</label>
                <tab>news</tab>
                <resource>Ktpl_Gmailsmtp::system_config</resource>
                <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>General Settings</label>
                    <field id="enable_in_frontend" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Enable in frontend</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    </field>
                    <field id="head_title" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Head title</label>
                        <comment>Fill head title of news list page at here</comment>
                        <validate>required-entry</validate>
                    </field>
                    <field id="lastest_news_block_position" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Lastest news block position</label>
                        <source_model>News\LatestNews\Model\System\Config\LastestNews\Position</source_model>
                    </field>
                </group>
            </section>
        </system>
    </config>
```

Comment: If this solution solved your problem then you can upvote and accept answer so it will help other